# How to make sure an interface only include properties from another interface?

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following interface.

```js
interface Client {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  cellNumberFull: string;
}
```

And I want the following interface to only include properties that exist in `GoClient`.

```
interface ClientRestricted {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  cellNumberFull: string;
  foo: string; // This would throw an error
}
```

Looking for some king of an opposite of extend. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to have your interface extend a mapped conditional type which is a function of itself.  It's a recursive type definition (called [F-bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)) that lets you do some fairly powerful (if confusing) type constraints.  For example:

```
type Restrict<T, U> = { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never };
type RestrictClient<U> = Restrict<Client, U>;

// okay as desired
interface Okay extends RestrictClient<Okay> {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  cellNumberFull: string;
}

// error, as desired
interface Extra extends RestrictClient<Extra> {
  //      ~~~~~
  // Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  cellNumberFull: string;
  foo: string;
}
```

By making your new interface `I extends RestrictClient<I>`, this will work if and only if `I` is assignable to `RestrictClient<I>`, meaning if `I` is assignable to `{[K in keyof I]: K extends keyof Client ? Client[K] : never}`, meaning if each key `K` of `I` is present in `Client` and is of the same (or narrower) type.

That also gives the following behavior, which may or may not fix your use case:

```
// okay to narrow properties
interface Narrowed extends RestrictClient<Narrowed> {
  firstName: "specificString";
}

// error to widen properties
interface Widened extends RestrictClient<Widened> {
  //      ~~~~~~~ <-- number not assignable to string
  firstName: string | number;
}

// error to change property to unrelated types
interface Unrelated extends RestrictClient<Unrelated> {
  //      ~~~~~~~~~ <-- number not assignable to string
  firstName: number;
}
```

If it doesn't match exactly what you're looking for, you might be able to change the definition of `Restrict` to align more closely with it.  Anyway, hope this gives you some ideas.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBtgXMg3gKGWWABMAuZEAVwFsAjaAbkOQhrmHQoGcwpQA5syIxgUXgDk4NCDz6DhydHEnTZyXvxBCWSdOgm0GUAGJV9crToC++fGACeABxQAlCJuAIwAHgAqADTIAKoAfMgAvHjIANoA0sQgyADWEA4A9jAhALoUCRAAHpAgJNwpaZnIfsgA-FXx2cgUIBAAbtDI1syOLsjunt4YWOA+YZF9HvLePkPYYEFhzPgA9MvI6clwDsgqyCQeYhAk+KCQsIgoAPKb24XFpRMDYLMj11vhBCJiqjKWCizKH7qTzaRR6AxGaBmCwaeSg-C2FZraBQdJQIK7fbcQ7HU7QeBIZAAUSKUDgrCK2Ae-Smz0wcx8JL4cA+LFWRA5yAAfjyeWy1n5nB51lknKiXFBHMgAOQwdLpaU7KAoUAIdI0JxwMDAOjoCAAOn5VSFMpBAkVwDKIHSYB23GxAhAcF1KDA6WQPRQ0pa7Sg0sNX3EYCkv1hVkUgODaj+8KI4MM9Ch5i4Yf+InlMZsdnZGy2HvdTqgqIA7sgxekJdqPCdwPiLsgpEX0sWjhT7mUafxBvSRo2S0dWYGgRQAETcFwIYCiBAAZThAhHzER7JRaPzyGLpGwZfF0Cr3BrZwJKAA6luWiQ21SO5Mu3Thr4z-sL4PkOzOdzebzkD4ALS-yhISgSgbTtB0nRddczRYUQgxDYF52QAAfQDEygJds2RJtgLdZAEAACzgbQUHLSttlwqgQGVZRIEvT0Dzxc5CWCKiIBo1s7mvR5aReXwWOorUBzwI0Py-MSf3-VDjBA20VHA509Sg+cYO+KNQ2oNCMKAA)